# How to save a 32 bit png with alpha channel (transparency) in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png, save

I want to use an image as an application launcher icon for my android application.

The android guidelines specify an image for the launcher icon must be a 32 bit PNG image.

Please explain the steps necessary to create a 32 bit png file with alpha.

Or share a video link showing these steps, if any.

Answer (score 19):

Simply save/export a PNG24 image using Adobe Photoshop which contains transparency. Transparency is the remaining 8 bits.

24Bit PNG = 8 bits red, 8 bits blue, 8 bits green

32bit PNG = 8 bits red, 8 bits blue, 8 bits green, 8 bits alpha

Photoshop automatically creates a 32bit PNG image if you save a 24Bit PNG that contains transparent areas.

Comment: photoshop cc in 2019 doesn't seem to have any option to save as 24 bit or 32 bit PNG any more.  You can manually add an alpha channel, and manually set it to use 8 bits for RGB, but still cant figure out how to save as 32bit PNG for android icons.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. Having an alpha channel and having the transparency check box selected does not result in a 32 bit export.

Answer (score 4):

Go first to Save for web option in Photoshop and save image in 24bit png and checked on transparency.

24 bit png image + transparency (8 bit) .

thats created automatically 32 bit png image.

Comment: Sadly, save for web has gone, and the "export as" is missing this feature.

Answer (score -1):

you can hit 
file>export>export as
then choose all specs required

Answer (score -2):

You can save 32bit PNG in Photoshop CC. Choose File-Export-Save for Web (Legacy), and then choose Preset PNG24 and check Transparency box.

Comment: Hi Random and welcome to GDSE! Please don't forget to check a date of the post you're contributing to and if it already has an answer you're giving. Cheers